# Save a file on an sftp server in php

Tags: php, server, upload, sftp

I have a problem I use Dropzone to upload a file, I have to save it on an sftp server, the connection with the server is fine.

but the fopen function still gives me an error:

> Warning: fopen(ssh2.sftp://Resource id #624/DossierTest/Extranet.png):
> failed to open stream: operation failed

However, I tested for example to create a file and no worries .. I do not know what to do!

here is my code:

```
$conn_id = ssh2_connect($ftp_server, 22) or die("Erreur de connexion avec le serveur FTP");
           $login_result = ssh2_auth_password($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

      
       if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {  // check connection
           // wont ever hit this, b/c of the die call on ftp_login
           $errorMessage= "<span style='color:#FF0000'><h2>FTP connection has failed! <br />";
           $errorMessage += "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name</h2></span>";
           exit;
       } else {
           $message = "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name <br />";
           //echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name <br />";
           $sftp = ssh2_sftp($conn_id);
         
           $stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/DossierTest/$file_name","w");
           $file = file_get_contents($local_path);
           fwrite($stream, $file);
           fclose($stream);`
```

I am trying with ssh2_scp_send
but I don't know what to put in 'local_file' and "remote_file"
Is this the name of the file or the absolute path to the file ??

I tried:
`ssh2_scp_send($conn_id,$local_path,"ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp)."/DossierTest/$file_name");`
and I have this error:
Warning: ssh2_scp_send (): Failure creating remote file: (null)

I tried:
`ssh2_scp_send($conn_id,$local_path,"/DossierTest/$file_name");` 
and it doesn't work either!
In locale_path I have the path "c: /wamp32/tmp/php9356.tmp" ?? is it good  ?
I admit there I am lost !! 3 days that I am looking for the solution !!
No one to help me ??
I'm really depressed!

Well, it's progressing I have no more errors!
with this code:

```
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {  // check connection
            // wont ever hit this, b/c of the die call on ftp_login
            $errorMessage= "<span style='color:#FF0000'><h2>FTP connection has failed! <br />";
            $errorMessage += "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name</h2></span>";
            exit;
        } else {
            $message = "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name <br />";
            //echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name <br />";
            $sftp = ssh2_sftp($conn_id);

            ssh2_scp_send($conn_id,$local_path,"/in/$file_name");
```

on the other hand when I go to look on the server the file sent a not found !!

Comment: add more details and also reupload file and clear cache also

Comment: *"However, I tested for example to create a file and no worries .. I do not know what to do!"* – Can you example this? Does it mean that you can upload some files and some not?

Comment: You'll need to get the intval of your SSH2 SFTP resource when calling fopen. Can you try doing this instead: `fopen("ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp)."/DossierTest/$file_name","w")`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl this function works: `ssh2_sftp_mkdir ($sftp, "DossierTest2");`

Comment: Please do not post information in comment. Edit your question instead. + `ssh2_sftp_mkdir` does not create a file, it creates a folder. Can you upload the file anyhow? Did you try using `ssh2_scp_send`? Can you upload the same file using any commandline/GUI SFTP client?

Comment: Use absolute paths with `ssh2_scp_send`. The same way as with your current code.

Comment: Absolute path on the remote server. Not any URL. The `ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp)."` should not be there! + You didn't answer the rest of my question.

Comment: What help do you expect? You never provided the information we have asked for!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'm sorry, I'm French I have a bit of trouble with English so I didn't see where I hadn't answered.
I have an error also with ssh2_scp_send ()

Comment: 1) Can you upload the same file using any commandline/GUI SFTP client?  2) **What** error do you get with `ssh2_scp_send`?

Answer (score -1):

Your `$sftp` variable holds an SSH2 SFTP resource, so you can't just concat it as you do in your code when you call `fopen`.

According to the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php) you'll need to get the intval of your SSH2 SFTP resource when calling `fopen`:

`fopen("ssh2.sftp://" . intval($sftp) . "/DossierTest/$file_name", "w");`

Comment: If you check the user comments in the PHP documentation, you will see that people commonly use `$sftp` directly. So it possibly is not a problem (I did test it though).

Comment: @jjnadoux45 Do you get the _exact_ same error message or did it change?